# Checking for the existence of an element in array full of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have an array of likes which includes the ids of the users that have liked the post (this is originally a mongoose model). I want to check if the user's id is in the array.

```
const likes =  
[
    {
        "user": "6283986e931a243f64eb063e"
    },
    {
        "user": "6283986e931a243f64eb0123s"
    },
]

const user = "6283986e931a243f64eb063e";

const hasBeenLiked = Object.values(likes).includes(user);

console.log(hasBeenLiked) //returns false
```

Obviously i cannot check this way. I am aware that i can do this with loop, but i want more lightweight approach (if possible).

The orignal code is:

```
const hasBeenLiked = Object.values(article.likes).includes(req.headers.user);
```

If this is not possible without the use of loops is there a mongoose command for this?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try with:
`const hasBeenLiked = likes.findIndex(l => l.user === user) !== -1 ? true : false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.some()`

```
const hasBeenLiked = likes.some(like => like.user === user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

const hasBeenLiked = !!likes.find(l => l.user == user)